# SQL Hashbytes command Output

Tags: sql-server

Why in SQL Server does the Hashbytes command return different responses in the following codes?

```
Declare @Pass nvarchar
set @Pass='SampleHash'
Select HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pass)
Select HASHBYTES('MD5','SampleHash')

---------------------------------------
0x6F0AC8C187CEDB835A9BA373603BDA3F

0xC205AF5CE2048FF5C8C9A5B5ABDAF64E
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: nvarchar is unicode, try with varchar and see the result.

Comment: You declared @Pass to be a single unicode character. And your literal is an ascii string of 10 characters.  Jacob posted the correct version without spelling out the biggest mistake - a single character string.

Comment: @SMor Yeah I changed the type automatically without even thinking because declaring any character type in sql without a length gives me the creeps. Edited to include that information.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring your string as unicode you will get the same `HASHBYTES` result:

```
Declare @Pass nvarchar(10)
set @Pass='SampleHash'
Select HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pass)
Select HASHBYTES('MD5',N'SampleHash')
```

`0xB8F6457C129AEBCBB0D2E3097336ED1C`

Or by using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`:

```
Declare @Pass varchar(10)
set @Pass='SampleHash'
Select HASHBYTES('MD5',@Pass)
Select HASHBYTES('MD5','SampleHash')
```

`0xC205AF5CE2048FF5C8C9A5B5ABDAF64E`

Edit: Note that I have also explicitly declared the lengths of the string values as `nvarchar(10)` or `varchar(10)` to match the length of the string `SampleHash`.